# Graphql query fails for deep local state in Apollo

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-link-state

I'm creating an apollo react application. I want apollo to manage my local state. I want to structure my local state so not all scalar values are at the top level.

This is my configuration:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { ApolloProvider, Query } from 'react-apollo'

const defaults = {
    author: null
}
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        author() {
            return { id: 1 }
        }
    }
}
const typedefs = gql(`
    type Query {
        author: Author
    }
    type Author {
        id: Int
    }
`)
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    clientState: {
        defaults,
        resolvers,
        typedefs
    },
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={ apolloClient }>
        <Query query={ gql`{ author @client }` }>
            { ({ data }) => console.log(data.author) || null }
        </Query>
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Then this app logs `undefined`. I.e., the query `{ author @client { id }}` returns `undefined` in data.author.

It must be noted that when I set the type of author as Int, default value as `1`, and I do the query `{ author @client }`, the app correctly logs `1`.

How can I have some structure in my local state with Apollo?

These are my relevant dependencies:

```
apollo-cache "^1.1.20"
apollo-cache-inmemory "^1.3.8"
apollo-client "^2.4.5"
apollo-link "^1.0.6"
apollo-link-error "^1.0.3"
apollo-link-http "^1.3.1"
apollo-link-state "^0.4.0"
graphql-tag "^2.4.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Apparently I had to add `__typename: 'Author'` to the defaults author this way:

```
const defaults = {
    author: {
        __typename: 'Author'
    }
}
```